# Accessing dynamically added listitems (using AJAX and jquery) on client side javascript before final Post

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

What I have working:
Get server names from database on search as you type and populate the Listbox with the items from Database using Ajax.

What I need to get working:
Need to allow user to select the items in the populated listbox and add them to another listbox (clientside javascript) and this will continue until the user has selected all the servers required. Note, the user will start a new search and the first listbox will refresh but the 2nd listbox (SelServers) persists with the selection that user has already made.
After the user is satisfied the list is ready for Postback.

Where am I stuck:
Unable to access the items that were dynamically added in the 1st listbox on client side.

Here is my html code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AutoComplete.aspx.cs" Inherits="AutoCompleteServers.AutoComplete" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 253px;
        }

        .auto-style2 {
            width: 258px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 100px" class="container">
            <div style="padding: 100px;">
                <div>
                    <br />
                    &nbsp;<br />
                    <br />
                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtServerSearch" runat="server" Width="240"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style2">
                                <label for="SelServers">Selected Server:</label></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                                <asp:ListBox ID="AutofillServerList" runat="server" Width="240" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style2">
                                <asp:ListBox runat="server" name="SelServers" ID="SelServers">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value="None" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:ListBox>

                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1" colspan="2">
                                <input type="button" onclick="setValue()" value="AddItem" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>

        function setValue() {
            console.log("Inside setvalue...");
            var AutofillServerList = $("#AutofillServerList");
            alert(AutofillServerList);

            var myvalue = AutofillServerList.options[AutofillServerList.selectedIndex].value;


            var SelServers = $("#SelServers");
            SelServers.append($("<option></option>").val(myvalue).html(myvalue));
        }


        $(function () {
            $("#txtServerSearch").on('keyup', function () {
                console.log("Inside function...");
                //$("[id*=AutofillServerList]").hide();
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    var servername = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "AutoComplete.aspx/NewGetServers",
                        data: "{'servername':'" + servername + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (r) {
                            var AutofillServerList = $("#AutofillServerList");
                            AutofillServerList.empty();
                            //AutofillServerList.multiselect({
                            //    includeSelectAllOption: true
                            //});
                            $.each(r.d, function () {
                                AutofillServerList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                            });

                            //$("[id*=AutofillServerList]").show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my code behind that populates the data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace AutoCompleteServers
{
    public partial class AutoComplete : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        [WebMethod]
        public static List<ListItem> NewGetServers(string servername)
        {

            List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
            string connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\MyLocalDatabase;Database=ChefDB;Integrated Security=true;";
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string sqlquery = string.Format("SELECT top 100 Name FROM [chefDB].[dbo].[Server] where Name LIKE '%{0}%'", servername);
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                items.Add(new ListItem
                {
                    Value = sdr["Name"].ToString(),
                    Text = sdr["Name"].ToString()
                    
                });

            }
            sqlconn.Close();
            return items;
        }

    }
}
```

The setvalue() function is not retrieving value on this line

```
 var myvalue = AutofillServerList.options[AutofillServerList.selectedIndex].value;
```

Error: reading 'undefined"

I am new to asp and open to any different approach to handle this requirement.
**Note:** Avoiding postback as server list huge and need to make user experience fast with AJAX

Comment: JavaScript is a Client side scripting language, meaning it loads after the HTML has been gathered from the Web Server. So you cannot call on code behind, only the resulting HTML. So your JavaScript must only reference the loaded document.

Comment: It might be easier to just use `$("#AutofillServerList").val()`

Comment: @Twisty your suggestion works !

Comment: Now trying to access the listbox on serverside after submit click, the value is null
Tried using
```
Request.Form[SelServers.UniqueID]```

Comment: You might run into the ViewState issue on the backend accessing the items. Because the backend doesn't know that the second list contains any items and doesn't "see" that you added them - as it only know the ones added in the backend. You have a choice to use UpdatePanel or a hidden field and Javascript to remember the selections.

Comment: Could you please help with code snippet or reference that I can look at ?